# Magento 2.2.3 showing error on checkout page on payment time

Tags: checkout, paypal, payment, magento2.2.3

Error is :

> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated

And infinite loop image not removing and no payment going to succeed in PayPal payflow .

Paypal responce is :

> Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the
>   fields below and try again.   Error: Secure Token is not enabled.
>   Please return to the website from where you started your purchase and
>   try again.

Please check : http://prntscr.com/jgky72 and http://prntscr.com/jgjswp

Anyone know what is solution?

Answer (score 3):

The secure token, utilized as part of a PPA integration, helps protect transaction data. You must use a secure token with hosted checkout pages. The token is good for one transaction and is valid for 30 minutes. The token and its token ID are used by the server to retrieve and display the transaction data for customer approval.

**Set up hosted checkout pages**

1. Using the PayPal Payments Advanced account, log in to PayPal Manager.
2. In the Service Summary section of the page, under Service, click Hosted Checkout Pages.
3. On the landing page titled Hosted Checkout Pages, click Set Up.
4. In the Payment Confirmation section of the page, enter a return URL (for use if the consumer proceeds with payment). For the return URL method, specify POST.
5. **Enable Secure Token. Set to Yes**.

On this Set Up page, click Save Changes.

[Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/#set-up-hosted-checkout-pages)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Wondering why this hasn't been accepted as the solution?